# Support Vector Machine one vs one training

Tags: opencv, image-processing, svm, libsvm

i am doing image classification using Opencv svm. My classification problem is classifying objects like cars, books, etc.Once i determine the model i add the test image to the training set and than train the system using 1 vs all training method.

But this is a very computationally expensive case since I have to train the system after adding the classified frames based on its group. Later I changed it to train after adding 5 frame, than 10 frames but it seems too expensive interms of computing.

I came across a method which I dont know how it works that is One vs One Training. I need some help in implementing 1 vs 1 training so that I dont train the entire training set of different class but just the one the test image belong to.

My confusion is : How i combine the training information after training separately?

Maybe I am treating the concept incorrectly as I am new to SVM so in that case be just help me out.

Comment: Please provide a reference for "one vs one training".

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you succesfully trained the SVMs on pairs of classes. Now you wonder how to combine the answers of these SVMs to get the final decision.

Usually the maximum voting strategy is used for that.

If you have a SVM that was trained to distinguish between class A and class B, depending on the output, it casts a vote for either class A or class B. You do that for all the SVMs you have trained. Then the class that got the most votes wins.

Comment: Thanks, so for eg. if Class A = Car and Class B = Book than i train them separately using one class training. Is it correct. 2) Than i predict the test image with both the trained classes right? Now my confusion is using the voting. If I have 2 classes than if I check the car than i will get say true (1) for class A and -1(false) in B. How is the voting working in here? Sorry as i am new to SVM i am little confused. Can you help me out with this please

Comment: You might confuse One-vs-One and One Class classification. In One-vs-One you take a binary SVM and train with pairs of classes. But you seem to use One Class SVMs, where only a single class is used for training. In this case you could use the class with the biggest distance to the margin, just like in the One-vs-All method. This would be useful in case there is not exactly one SVM returning 'true'/